# How to construct a Observable with custom numbers and different delays?

Tags: java, scala, reactive-programming, rx-scala, reactivex

In order to test my reactive program with rxscala, I need to construct such an `Observable`:

```
val numberStream: Observable[Int] = Observable.???()
```

which

1. publishes number `1`
2. then waits for `1s`
3. publishes number `4`
4. then waits for `3s`
5. publishes number `2`
6. then waits for `2s`

I have a ugly solution, with `Thread` and `ReplaySubject`:

```
val subject: Subject[Int] = ReplaySubject()
val numberStream: Observable = subject

new Thread(new Runnable {
    def run = {
        subject.onNext(1)
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        subject.onNext(4)
        Thread.sleep(3000)
        subject.onNext(2)
        Thread.sleep(2000)
    }
}).start()
```

Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could concatenate together several Observable with delays, with the final Observable being and `empty` with a subscription delay.

```
val numberStream = (
     Observable.just(1) ++ 
     Observable.just(4).delay(1.second) ++
     Observable.just(2).delay(3.second) ++
     Observable.empty.delaySubscription(2.second))
```

As a side note, if you are testing you should be using a `TestScheduler` which you can pass as the second argument to `delay`.